# Resttemplate ExceptionMapper doesn't handl exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, resttemplate

I'm using Spring RestClientException in ExceptionMapper for handling exception message but my mapper stay not working when I debug the method **toResponse** was not called and stay have exception message this my code  :

```
@Provider
@Component
public class RestClientExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RestClientException> {

    /** Logger */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestClientExceptionMapper.class);

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public RestClientExceptionMapper() {
    }


    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final RestClientException rce) {

        // Tracer l'erreur rest
        LOGGER.error("Une erreur a eu lieu lors de la communication avec le WS REST : ", rce);

        // Renvoyer une erreur en résultat
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(new RestDataOut(BusinessError.WS_CALL_ERROR, false)).build();
    }

}
```

This is the result after a bad request stay have 404 error How I can do to fix this problem Thank you in advance 
[image]